# Can plugins listen to events in different groups?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, plugin-events, jevents

I'm trying to trigger some actions for example when a content article is saved (using `onContentAfterSave`) or when a event from jEvents (https://www.jevents.net/) is saved (using `onAfterSaveEvent`). The last one is a custom event that is not present on the core Joomla groups.

Is it possible to create a single plugin that can listen to events of different groups or do I need to create multiple plugins for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the plugin is instantiated. This is done when the plugin group is imported. The common way is to create a plugin in `system` group because those are always imported. Beware that plugin execution order depends on group import order. Since system plugins are imported very early, they'll run before any other plugins.

Comment: Custom plugin groups can't achieve this behavior right? Another question, can components listen to events? I would like to avoid plugins, since I already got a component.

Comment: Not without a system plugin first to import the groups. Same goes for a component.